# Deleting part of string from hidden box - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one hidden box which contains value like (,1420,1254,1258,124,1235). These values are IDs which are populated based on the description selected by user through Select Box. If user selects any description and removes it from Select Box then corresponding ID should be removed from the Hidden box. I can only use Javascript to do this. I tried using replace method but it is not supported and also my application works only in IE browser.

Could anyone let me know how to get this done?

TIA

Comment: Show the code that you tried

Comment: The `.replace()` method should be supported even on the most obsolete browsers I can think of. Unless it was overridden elsewhere for some weirdo reason.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your **code**, this is the most we can help you with

```
function removeId(hiddenBox,id){
  var idList = hiddenBox.innerHTML;
  idList = idList.customReplace(','+id,'');
  hiddenBox.innerHTML = idList;
}
```

**And since you said the replace method is not working for some reason (which is weird), here is a custom replace method**

*I'm hoping the indexOf(), length and substring() methods are still working*

```
String.prototype.customReplace = function(from,to){
    var string = String(this);
    var newString = "";
    var startIndex = string.indexOf(from);
    if(startIndex == -1) return string;
    var endIndex = startIndex + from.length;
    newString = string.substring(0,startIndex);
    newString += to;
    newString += string.substring(endIndex,string.length);
    return newString;
}
```